# Can't select, update or delete from a table because of a 'JSON text is not properly formatted... ' error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

For the first 3 statements below, the select/delete/update are causing an error:

> "JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '.' is found at position 0."

I don't know why since I am not using any JSON functions. I expect the select to get data as is and the delete and update statements to just do their work regardless of any JSON data in any column.

The `ISJSON` is returning 1 for the `UserPreferences` column since this is the only column that might have json data based on the insert statement.

I'm using SQL Server 2019. This table is a copy of a table from the `WideWorldImporters` sample database.

Any idea why the first 3 statements are failing?

Also, is there a quick way to find which column is causing it without a separate select for each column?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Application.People p 
WHERE p.PersonID = 1  -- error

UPDATE Application.People 
SET UserPreferences = NULL 
WHERE PersonID = 1 -- error

DELETE FROM Application.People  -- error

SELECT ISJSON(p.UserPreferences) 
FROM Application.People p 
WHERE p.PersonID = 1 -- = 1

SELECT p.UserPreferences 
FROM Application.People p 
WHERE p.PersonID = 1 -- returns a value
```

Insert statement and Table's DDL:

```
INSERT INTO Application.People (PersonID, FullName, PreferredName, IsPermittedToLogon, LogonName, IsExternalLogonProvider, IsSystemUser, IsEmployee, IsSalesperson, UserPreferences, PhoneNumber, FaxNumber, EmailAddress, CustomFields, LastEditedBy)  
VALUES ('1', 'Data Conversion Only', 'Data Conversion Only', 'False', 'NO LOGON', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', '{"theme":"blitzer","dateFormat":"yy-mm-dd","timeZone": "PST","table":{"pagingType":"full_numbers","pageLength": 25},"favoritesOnDashboard":true}', '', '', '', '', '1');

CREATE TABLE [Application].[People]
(
    [PersonID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FullName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PreferredName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SearchName]  AS (CONCAT([PreferredName],N' ',[FullName])) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [IsPermittedToLogon] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LogonName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [IsExternalLogonProvider] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [HashedPassword] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [IsSystemUser] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsEmployee] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsSalesperson] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [UserPreferences] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [FaxNumber] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [EmailAddress] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [Photo] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [CustomFields] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [OtherLanguages]  AS (json_query([CustomFields],N'$.OtherLanguages')),
    [LastEditedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ValidFrom] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
    [ValidTo] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Application_People] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PersonID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [USERDATA],
        PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([ValidFrom], [ValidTo])
) ON [USERDATA] TEXTIMAGE_ON [USERDATA]
WITH
(SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [Application].[People_Archive]))
GO

ALTER TABLE [Application].[People] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Application_People_PersonID]  
        DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR [Sequences].[PersonID]) FOR [PersonID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Application].[People]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Application_People_Application_People] 
        FOREIGN KEY([LastEditedBy])
        REFERENCES [Application].[People] ([PersonID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Application].[People] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Application_People_Application_People]
GO
```

Comment: Perhaps your computed column, `[OtherLanguages]  AS (json_query([CustomFields],N'$.OtherLanguages'))`, could check whether or not `[CustomFields]` contains a valid JSON value before trying to parse it?

Comment: Thanks. I came to the same conclusion after I did a select on each column.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning `''` which is being inserted is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select error was because of a computed column that used the json_query function on another column which had an empty string.

The delete and update errors were due to the temporal table Application.People. When I dropped the history table, the errors went out. I am guessing it's related to the computed column. The database is on my dev machine and I don't care about history tables.

Answer (score 1):

Your computed column definition is causing problems.

```sql
[OtherLanguages]  AS (json_query([CustomFields], N'$.OtherLanguages'))
```

If a value in the table is not valid JSON then this will error. Note that an empty string `''` is not valid JSON, you should use `NULL` instead.

You **must** ensure this can't happen, so use `CASE` and `ISJSON` to short-circuit.

```sql
[OtherLanguages]  AS (CASE WHEN ISJSON([CustomFields]) = 1 THEN JSON_QUERY([CustomFields], N'$.OtherLanguages') END)
```

You may instead want to add a constraint to ensure it's valid JSON

```sql
ALTER TABLE [Application].[People]
ADD CONSTRAINT CustomFields_IsJson
  CHECK (ISJSON([CustomFields]) = 1);
```